# Stop Location Updates after first time

Tags: android

I am using a service which implements LocationListener class.Now i want to know the current location(Latitude,Longitude) of the device. I have used requestLocationUpdates method so that onLocationChanged method gets called when the location changes. I want that onLocationChanged method should be called only once i.e. when i get the location for the first time, it should not be called again.
I have called stopSelf method to stop the service inside onLocationChanged method. But still i am getting location updates.
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [removeUpdates](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) on `LocationManager`, passing your location listener.

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
```